# Reusing widgets with Bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

**What do I want to achieve?**

I'm using the *Flutter BLoc* library for my authentication component. Inside login page I have some text fields like username/password that I'm going to share with other pages as well, such as register page, forgot password, change password etc. Basically, following the *DRY* principle.

Each page (Register, Login, Forgot Password etc.) has it's own BLoc component.

**My problem**
I couldn't find a way to decouple the widget from the BLoc. I want to be able pass in the stateful widget any BLoc component depending on the page it is used in.

To make sense out of the written above let's take a look at my code.

**login.dart** A of piece of code from the build method from the Login page.

```
Widget _loginForm(){
    return BlocListener<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        final status = state.formStatus;
        if (status is SubmissionFailed) {
         ...
        }
      },
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            // The reusable widget: Email input field.
            BlocBuilder<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
              builder:(context, state){
                return emailInputField(context, state);
              }
            ),
            ...
```

Now let's take a look in the **emailInputField** widget

```
Widget emailInputField(BuildContext context, dynamic state) {
  return TextFormField(
    validator: (value) =>
        state.isValidEmail ? null : 'Please input a valid email',
    onChanged: (value) =>
        // HERE - I want to decouple this widget from "LoginBloc".
        context.read<LoginBloc>().add(LoginUsernameChanged(username: value)),
      labelText: 'Email',
    ...
  );
}
```

**login_bloc.dart** The Login BLoc

```
class LoginBloc extends Bloc<BaseEvent, LoginState>{
  LoginBloc() : super(LoginState());

  @override
  Stream<LoginState> mapEventToState(BaseEvent event) async*{
    yield* event.handleEvent(state);
  }

}
```

And the login events class, for having a full picture **login_event.dart**

```
abstract class LoginEvent extends BaseEvent {
  AuthenticationService authService = GetIt.I.get<AuthenticationService>();
}

// Event 1
class LoginUsernameChanged extends LoginEvent {
  final String username;

  LoginUsernameChanged({this.username});

  @override
  Stream<LoginState> handleEvent(BaseState state) async* {
    // Dart style down-casting...
    LoginState loginState = state;
    yield loginState.copyWith(username: username);
  }
}
```

**base_event.dart**

```
abstract class BaseEvent {
  Stream<BaseState> handleEvent(BaseState state);
}
```

And again, is there a way to decouple that view from the BLoc?
I hope my question makes sense after reading this.

P.S

To make things even simpler, one idea I though of is to keep one single Bloc component that will handle a group of related input fields (password/username) and then just pass in different states as I did in **login.dart** page when calling the emailInput widget.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I would do is decouple the widget from bloc entirely. Instead of taking the bloc `state` and using `bloc.add`, create dependencies that you can populate with any parameter.

In you example you would have:

```dart
Widget emailInputField({
 required BuildContext context, 
 required bool isValidEmail, 
 required void Function(String?) onChange,
}) {
  return TextFormField(
    validator: (value) => isValidEmail ? null : 'Please input a valid email',
    onChanged: onChange,
    labelText: 'Email',
    ...
  );
}
```

Then you can use `emailInputField` with any bloc you want. Or any state management library for that matter.

For your example this would give:

```dart
Widget _loginForm(){
    return BlocListener<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        final status = state.formStatus;
        if (status is SubmissionFailed) {
         ...
        }
      },
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            // The reusable widget: Email input field.
            BlocBuilder<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
              builder:(context, state){
                return emailInputField(
                  context: context,
                  isValidEmail: state.isValidEmail, 
                  onChanged: (value) => context.read<LoginBloc>().add(LoginUsernameChanged(username: value))
                );
              }
            ),
            ...
```

Comment: This is a great idea, but how do I pass the new value to the onChange function?

Comment: See my updated answer